# Starling filter : invert alpha

Tags: actionscript-3, shader, fragment-shader, stage3d, starling-framework

I try to make a shader for Starling that will invert alpha (a kind of mask) of a Starling sprite :

```
var fragmentProgramCode:String =
// Get texture
"tex ft1, v0, fs0 <2d,linear,nomip>" + "\n" +
// make 1 - pixel alpha
"sub ft1.w, fc0, ft1.w" + "\n" +
// Send result
"mov oc, ft1"
```

This code works With fc0 = 1 but I don't realy understand why because when I play with fc0 and put into it .5, there is no difference. Where am I wrong ? How to properly do 1 - pixel alpha ?

Comment: Does your shader receive any input in `v0`? The manual states that v0 should be filled with UV first.

Comment: I think, FragmentShader from starling automaticaly set : vertex constants 0-3: mvpMatrix (3D), vertex attribute 0: vertex position (FLOAT_2), vertex attribute 1: texture coordinates (FLOAT_2) and 
 texture 0: input texture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right code was : `"sub ft1.w, fc0.x, ft1.w" + "\n" +`

I must use fc0.x because the alpha amount was pass to fragment shader through the first entry (fc0 have 4 components, x y z and w).

You will find final filter here : https://gist.github.com/simsoft/5169715

[image: Alpha inverter filter]